# How do I create PickerView using code alone (no xib)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not able to find examples for this, Can someone help - I need to create PickerView triggered from clicking a UIButton, filling data from Array or Dictionary without using .xib designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `IBAction` method of the `UIButton` you can do

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
    [myPicker release];
}
```

you would have to implement the delegate and datasource methods to show the picker and its contents.